# MongoRepository Query issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I´m using MongoRepository, and I creating a query.
Maybe is a stupid issue but I cannot find the solution.
I have this @Query:

```
@Query("{'offerConfiguration.initOffer' : {'$lt' : ?0}, 'offerConfiguration.endOffer' : {'$gt' : ?1}, 'offerConfiguration.offerType': ?2, " +
        "$or: [{transactionStatus:'PAYPAL_DONE'}, {transactionStatus:'PAYMILL_DONE'}]}")
```

What I understand is that I´m trying to find all documents where the date is between two dates(That part works), that the offer type, Let´s said is product, and the TransactionStatus is PAYPAL_DONE or PAYMILL_DONE.
The problem is that if I put the transactionStatus filter the result give me documents where offerType is not like I specify. As long as I understand this part "'offerConfiguration.offerType': ?2" is an AND, so if is not true we should not receive any document. 
What I´m doing wrong?!?

Comment: Have you tried run this query on mongo shell? What was the result?

Comment: Same result :( I dont know what I´m doing wrong!

Comment: When the query have an $or, mongo executes _n_ queries in parallel and then merge the results. So what is the result if you query this: {"offerConfiguration.initOffer": {"$lt": ?0},"offerConfiguration.endOffer": {"$gt": ?1},"offerConfiguration.offerType": ?2,"transactionStatus: 'PAYPAL_DONE'}?